# How to get the count of messages with someone in Facebook

Tags: facebook

I want to know the number of messages I have with anyone on Facebook.

Is there some way to know the count of messages that have been exchanged between me and someone else?

Comment: Are you talking about Wall Posts between people or Direct (Personal) Messages?

Comment: Direct messages (Private)

Comment: I mean the personal messages

Comment: This was answered in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an easy way to do it: go to your messages in Facebook and then click on the conversation you want the count from. Scroll very fast up in the conversation, now there stands "loading xxxx messages".

Comment: This no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

The programmers's way is the only way to do it. This cannot be done from within Facebook.

Facebook itself has no such option. Facebook does has an API, but it does not allows the apps to go up to the level of interacting with the messages of its users.

Comment: @just_name I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

This App for Facebook Message Count. You can search in Facebook "Message count" or click link :)
http://apps.facebook.com/messagecount/

Comment: It doesn't include archived chats.

Comment: @marines: but you can have a quick view of message number of many friend.

Comment: This page is now 404

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do the following to accomplish that:

1. first open all conversations
2. then open any person's chat you want to count
3. then move upwards very quickly in that conversations
4. then it will show loading messages:

> **amount of messages is**

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Stack Overflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894889/get-count-chat-message)

> you can look at FQL Thread table see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/thread/ field message_count

Comment: hmmmmm. this 's in a programming way . i just need to know this through the facebook as an appliaction

Comment: This documentation is no longer available.